# Make new folder on server with applescript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to create a new folder on a server with a name that was taken from the user. Here is what I have so far

```
display dialog "Please enter your augnet username" default answer "username"
set username to (text returned of result)

mount volume "smb://orgs.augsburg.edu"

tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at "orgs.augsburg.edu/Information Technology/www/kb_images/Migration Testing" with properties {name:username}
end tell
```

I am getting an error saying "cannot make into type item"
any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does it say what line the error is on? I don't see an "item" but a "folder".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error because :

1 - The type of this path is "posix path", the **Finder** does not recognize this type, slashes should be replaced by colons

2- You must specify the class (**folder, files, disk**, ...) when you use a string (the path) in the Finder

```
display dialog "Please enter your augnet username" default answer "username"
set username to (text returned of result)

mount volume "smb://orgs.augsburg.edu"
tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at folder "orgs.augsburg.edu:Information Technology:www:kb_images:Migration Testing:" with properties {name:username}
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you! This has gotten me much closer!

Comment: Although this solves the issue for OP, both parts of the answer are only partially correct. The issue is Finder handles *Finder Item* objects, of which *folder* is a descendant, and these can be **implicitly** created from AppleScript *alias* objects and their textual representation, which is a path in HFS notation (colons as path separators). Using a path in POSIX notation will work too if you **explictly** convert, i.e. `make new folder at folder (POSIX file "/path/to/folder")`. Finally, I’d recommend using *System Events* instead of Finder, as it works in the background and is much faster.